# Having trouble extracting date param from form submission

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arguments, form-submit, date-format

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with MySQL 5.5.37.  I have a DATE field in my model and the following on my form …

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :day %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :day, :class => 'datepicker' %>
</div>
```

Because my datepicker converts has the date format as “mm/dd/yy” and MySQL requires it to be “yyyy-MM-dd”, I want to convert the date string.  So in my controller I have

```
@date = DateTime.parse(params[:day])
@mysql_formatted_date = @date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
@user_object = UserObject.find_by_user_id_and_object_and_day(@current_user.id, params[:object], @mysql_formatted_date)
```

but Rails is complaining, “no implicit conversion of nil into String”.  Is there an easier way to convert my date into a format in which it can be searched by MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jQuery UI's datepicker? If so, just set the field to have the format MySQL expects.

In coffeescript:

```
$('#day').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

Comment: after doing that, the call, "params[:day]" still produces nil despite the fact I have selected something in my datepicker.

Comment: Ah, everything worked when I used "user_object_params[:day]" isntead.